# Constraints to NavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, constraints

I have got a viewController that I push it into navigationController
The viewController contained an imageView that has a top constraint to top safe area, and I don't understand why but the imageView surpasses the navigation.

Can someone explain to me why and how should I fix it?

Thanks

This is the viewController xib

[image: This is the view controller xib]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into **Attributes inspector** in your storyboard.
Make sure that `Under Top Bars` in **Extend Edges** section isn't checked.

Comment: @TalBenAsulo did this help you?